# Highcharts correlation coefficients

Tags: highcharts, correlation

I tried to find a ready-made Highcharts solution for analyzing the correlation coefficients between the data series on the graph, but nothing comes out. Can someone faced such a problem?

Comment: Could you explain what kind of correlation would you like to show and in what way? I think that the best idea will be showing it in the tooltip. You should be able to display whatever you want in the tooltip using the `formatter` callback. API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter

Comment: I don't have a definite vision for the solution. As I see such functionality, we give rows with prices for several stocks for the chart input, and on the chart we have a calculated coefficient of correlation according to some built-in formula for this. But if there is no such functionality, then tooltip can be the solution to my question.

Comment: Please also take a look at technical indicators in the Highstock - maybe some of them will fit your requirements - https://www.highcharts.com/docs/stock/technical-indicator-series